# Unable to retrieve and save user’s display picture through cURL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am trying to retrieve users display picture through graph api and using cUrl to save it into the disk, but am unable succeed in it and getting this error when trying to check the mime type of the picture that I saved:

`Notice: exif_imagetype(): Read error! in`

```
//$userPpicture = $user_profile[picture];
//Create image instances
        $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{$userId}/picture?type=large";
        $dpImage = 'temp/' . $userId . '_dpImage_' . rand().'.jpg';
        echo $dpImage;

        function get_data($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            $timeout = 5;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        $returned_content = get_data($url);
        file_put_contents($dpImage, $returned_content);
        echo "Type: " . exif_imagetype($dpImage);
```

for this updated code using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` I am getting this error:

`Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when in safe_mode or an open_basedir is set in /var/fog/apps/app12345/myapp.phpfogapp.com/start.php on line 178`

**If this action requires any server side configuration then i might not be able to do this as am using a shared cloud storage over `phpfog`.**

Kindly help me with this.

Thankyou.

Comment: are you sure the permission was given to the app to access the picture?

Comment: yes ive all the required permissions.

Comment: @Sir - pictures via /id/picture are publicly available 
- Maven - have a look at the image in the temp directory - check you're getting what you expect - also try file_get_contents (it works with URLs)

Comment: also try `chmod` the file after `file_put_contents` - also what does `filesize( $dpImage )` give you?

Comment: @scibuff: due to server restriction i cant user `file_get_contents` & `fopen` functions.

Comment: `filesize($dpImage)` is returning `0`

Comment: right, that means that you probably can't even write the file;

Comment: yea so how i can correct this? is my code all correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph url you are using of http://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large returns a HTTP 302 redirect, not the actual user image.  You would need to follow the redirect and download the image at that url which is a url that looks like this: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/49942_4_1525300_n.jpg

Comment: Thank-you for reply, i followed you suggestion by allowing cURL to follow action (see my updated code), but now i am getting that new warning. please help.

Answer (score 0):

As OffBySome points out, you need to follow the 302 redirect served by graph.facebook.com to the final destination, which contains the actual image data.

The simplest way to do that in this case is to add another curl_setopt call with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION as true.  i.e.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true)`

Check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for more details.

Comment: Thank-you for reply, did that but now i am getting that new warning. (see my updated code),  please help.